Problems with corrupt boot files
I've been having problems with boot over the last few days. I have dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04, and suddenly neither system was able to boot properly. Originally I had the following output when booting Ubuntu:

Initial read: Device Error, buffersize 6000
Failed to load image: Device Error
start_image() returned Device Error

I tried different things (made some disks checks with windows, eventually got to something better on that end) and at some point Ubuntu disappeared as a boot option on the UEFI menu. I then ran BootRepair and it reappeared, only to show the same messagge as before, but this time with this at the start

failed to open grubx64.efi

This is the latest Boot-Repair report: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KzMxDyQjS9
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

ping: google.com: Name or service not known

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi of
sda5,
using the following options:  sda1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups


rm /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
Mount /dev/sda1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda5/boot/efi

===================== Reinstall the grub-efi of /dev/sda5 ======================

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda5 grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.06-2ubuntu7.2
modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-76-generic
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda5 modprobe efivars

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda5 efibootmgr -v before grub install
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0000,0004
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,651d7b91-6eec-4a54-ab1d-ece40f2fe115,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIMICROSOFTBOOTBOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...o................
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,651d7b91-6eec-4a54-ab1d-ece40f2fe115,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIUBUNTUSHIMX64.EFI)..BO
Boot0004* UEFI: SanDisk Cruzer Blade 1.20, Partition 1  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(2,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x1f502c,0x800,0xee83c8)..BO

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda5 uname -r
5.15.0-76-generic

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda5 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/sda1
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sda5/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda5/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/sda5/boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda5/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda5 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda5 efibootmgr -v after grub install
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0000,0004
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,651d7b91-6eec-4a54-ab1d-ece40f2fe115,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIMICROSOFTBOOTBOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...o................
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,651d7b91-6eec-4a54-ab1d-ece40f2fe115,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIUBUNTUSHIMX64.EFI)..BO
Boot0004* UEFI: SanDisk Cruzer Blade 1.20, Partition 1  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(2,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x1f502c,0x800,0xee83c8)..BO
Warning: NVram was not modified.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda5 update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-45-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS entry (sda1/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi /bootmgr /boot/bcd

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.04
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32776 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/boot/bootx64.efi /efi/boot/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/mmx64.efi /ldlinux.sys


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on sda5
OS#2:   Windows 8 or 10 on sda3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: HD Graphics 620 from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Linuxmint 64-bit (Linux Mint 21.2, victoria, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: UX410UAK.312(5.12) from American Megatrends Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0000,0004
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,651d7b91-6eec-4a54-ab1d-ece40f2fe115,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...o................
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,651d7b91-6eec-4a54-ab1d-ece40f2fe115,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)..BO
Boot0004* UEFI: SanDisk Cruzer Blade 1.20, Partition 1  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(2,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x1f502c,0x800,0xee83c8)..BO

a1da253696a304dce6b4668b70151c0e   sda1/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
a1da253696a304dce6b4668b70151c0e   sda1/Boot/bootx64.efi
a9c517741ac31962d7feb152948ad1ee   sda1/Boot/fbx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   sda1/Boot/mmx64.efi
a1da253696a304dce6b4668b70151c0e   sda1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   sda1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
23837e7f81b5b729c2cc673d3da56273   sda1/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi
e25c67909b3a3532861d8f798f7d7833   sda1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
2cf1d72d27e9fdbb7505c9dfa442f21a   sda1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda3    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda4    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda5    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda4    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda5    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda3    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda4    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda5    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 101E8206-A176-4932-B784-9E52FADD6916
          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
sda1        2048     534527     532480   260M EFI System
sda2      534528     567295      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
sda3      567296 1358784978 1358217683 647.6G Microsoft basic data
sda4  1951885312 1953523711    1638400   800M Windows recovery environment
sda5  1358786560 1935886169  577099610 275.2G Linux filesystem
sda6  1935886336 1951885311   15998976   7.6G Linux swap
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sdb: 7.45 GiB, 8004304896 bytes, 15633408 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x001f502c
     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *     2048 15633351 15631304  7.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA WD Green 2.5 100:;
1:1049kB:274MB:273MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:274MB:290MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:290MB:696GB:695GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
5:696GB:991GB:295GB:ext4::;
6:991GB:999GB:8191MB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;
4:999GB:1000GB:839MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;
sdb:8004MB:scsi:512:512:msdos:SanDisk Cruzer Blade:;
1:1049kB:8004MB:8003MB:fat32::boot, lba;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                   
├─sda1 vfat     6846-BE66                            651d7b91-6eec-4a54-ab1d-ece40f2fe115 SYSTEM      EFI system partition
├─sda2                                               2254c92a-e966-45ba-b286-88de48c20f5b             Microsoft reserved partition
├─sda3 ntfs     38643EB7643E7828                     e69b099d-c935-4cde-9010-7d39b6a13a73 OS          Basic data partition
├─sda4 ntfs     081A593F1A592B48                     e8bec7d8-78ba-448e-b156-7a4ab0f84c93             Basic data partition
├─sda5 ext4     d302b50b-a3ae-4d97-985c-9b09b276e46c c3eed210-0cb9-4589-aea0-2e68bd3177cf             
└─sda6 swap     7a6dba61-80d0-4341-9d01-00960d0c0390 8d2a55c8-2721-42ae-ba7f-68e776b141c2             
sdb                                                                                                   
└─sdb1 vfat     E45D-51BD                            001f502c-01                          BOOT-REPAIR 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

            Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1   201.5M  21% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda3   140.3G  78% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sda4   291.5M  64% /mnt/boot-sav/sda4
/dev/sda5   163.7G  34% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5
/dev/sdb1       5G  33% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda1   vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sda3   fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda4   fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda5   ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdb1   vfat            ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

===================== sda1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid d302b50b-a3ae-4d97-985c-9b09b276e46c root hd0,gpt5 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   d302b50b-a3ae-4d97-985c-9b09b276e46c
Windows Boot Manager (on sda1)   osprober-efi-6846-BE66
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda5/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=d302b50b-a3ae-4d97-985c-9b09b276e46c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=7a6dba61-80d0-4341-9d01-00960d0c0390 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/38643EB7643E7828 /media/seke/OS auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
UUID=6846-BE66  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

======================= sda5/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

==================== sda5: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 823.693355560 = 884.434006016  boot/vmlinuz                                   2
 685.909763336 = 736.490000384  boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-45-generic                  1
 823.693355560 = 884.434006016  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic                  2
 685.909763336 = 736.490000384  boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
 691.537105560 = 742.532313088  boot/initrd.img                                6
 771.794918060 = 828.708483072  boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-45-generic               7
 691.537105560 = 742.532313088  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic               6
 771.794918060 = 828.708483072  boot/initrd.img.old                            7

===================== sda5: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Dec 18  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Dec 18  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Dec 18  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Dec 18  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Dec 18  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Dec 18  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Dec 18  2022 41_custom

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Start Boot-Repair-Disk 64-bit
Start Boot-Repair-Disk 64-bit (compatibility mode)
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

========================= sdb1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1
sprunge.us ko ()

Multiple times while I'm in the UEFI menu and chose to boot Ubuntu the screen goes black for a second and immediately comes back to UEFI (which also happened a few times with Windows, but not as much.
I'm not sure if there's anything else of use I could add to the question, but let me know.
Edit:
I have an ASUS ZenBook UX410U with an Intel Core i3-7100U 2.40 GHz X4, and a Mesa Intel HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2) with a 1TB SSD.
I copies the grubx64.efi file from a Ubuntu installation drive and I started to be able to go through grub when it did boot (so I am able to access Recovery Mode). Sometimes it bypasses the Ubuntu boot (which is first on the UEFI order) and goes to Windows though.
At one point it showed the same error I had at first, but with buffersize 0 instead of 6000.
When I run sudo fcsk -f /dev/sdxx on the Linux filesystem partition using the installation drive the output is

913506/18038784 files (0.8% non-contiguous), 25698636/72137451 blocks


What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Can you press escape key just after UEFI/BIOS vendor logo, but before grub menu normally should appear to get grub menu? And boot in recovery mode?  Make sure UEFI does not have fast boot set on. That assumes no changes to boot configuration and then UEFI/BIOS does not update configuration for operating system. UEFI fast boot can make it difficult to press any key when booting as too quick. Full power down or "cold" boot often then works.

I have an ASUS ZenBook UX410U with an Intel Core i3-7100U 2.40 GHz X4, and a Mesa Intel HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)

Are you using a Mint ISO live installer to repair Ubuntu. You need to use Ubuntu. If dual booting with Windows make sure UEFI Secure boot is off, at least for the next week due to Microsoft revoking shimx64.efi. Update available with new ISO in a few days. Can you boot recovery mode?

I'm using an Ubuntu ISO. I turned Secure Boot off now, but I figured that wasn't the problem since the error looked different from the examples I saw for that issue. I can't boot recovery mode, it says there's an error reading a something and then gets stuck with a bunch of lines

Usually not last line, but several lines above will be an error or issue in the list of lines. Did just try booting from recovery mode or do the repairs? Some may need this: Problems Installing on ASUS F555U   needed boot option pci=nomsi
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2303665
